# Android HttpUrlConnection FileNotFoundException. Connect to http and pass params

Tags: android, post, httpurlconnection, filenotfoundexception

```
public class GeoRegistration extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, AuthorizationResponseContainer> {

private Activity activity;
private static final String USERNAME = "username=";
private static final String EMAIL = "&email=";
private static final String PASSWORD = "&password=";
private static final String PASSWORD_REPEAT = "&password_repeat=";
private String route;
private String paramsSequence;

public GeoRegistration() {
}

public GeoRegistration(Activity activity, String username, String email, String password, String passwordConfirm) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.route = activity.getResources().getString(R.string.domain) + activity.getResources().getString(R.string.registration_second_step_route);
    this.paramsSequence = USERNAME + username +
            EMAIL + email +
            PASSWORD + password +
            PASSWORD_REPEAT + passwordConfirm;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected AuthorizationResponseContainer doInBackground(Void... params) {
    String message = null;
    int code = 0;
    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(route);
        httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpURLConnection.setReadTimeout(10000);
        httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST"); //Sometimes (it's very strange, I catch ProtocolExeption: Connection already established)
        httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
        httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);

        /*PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(httpURLConnection.getOutputStream());
        out.print(this.paramsSequence);
        out.close();*/
        OutputStream os = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream(); 
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
        osw.write(paramsSequence);
        osw.flush();
        osw.close();

        httpURLConnection.connect();
        int status = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream())); //FileNotFounException
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(line + "\n");
        }
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(builder.toString());
        message = jsonObject.getString(ResponseKeys.MESSAGE);
        code = jsonObject.getInt(ResponseKeys.CODE);
        switch (status) {
            case 200:
                if (code == 0) {

                }
                return null;
            case 400:
                return new AuthorizationResponseContainer(ResponseKeys.CODE_400, code, message, null);
            case 500:
                return new AuthorizationResponseContainer(ResponseKeys.CODE_500, code, message, null);
        }
    } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (httpURLConnection != null) {
            try {
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

route: http://geo.binno.com.ua/api/m1/registration/
Why I can not get input stream from HttpUrlConnection? I catch FileNotFoundException. But when I do the same at the REST API CLIENT in browser, I can connect to host and receive json answer. What I do wrongly?
[image]

Comment: Remove httpURLConnection.connect(); You are already connected and wrote already to the output stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add these lines of code..

```
httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 ( compatible ) ");
httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*/*");
```

and

```
try {
    is = connection.getInputStream();
} catch(FileNotFoundException exception){
    log.error(exception.getMessage(), exception);
    is = connection.getErrorStream();
}
 BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
```

I hope this will resolve your problem. Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

I was passed http params as string, need as JSON - it's first.
When server ansver 4xx code - need get ErrorStream, not InputStream
Example:

```
int respCode = conn.getResponseCode();
Bufferreader reader;
switch(respCode){
case 200:
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream())); //to avoid FNFExeption
break;
case 400:
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getErrorStream())); //to avoid FNFExeption
break;
}
```